# scope not working on Mongoid (undefined method `to_criteria')

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I invoke `ReleaseSchedule.next_release` in other controller

and got the following error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_criteria' for #<ReleaseSchedule:0x007f9cfafbfe70>):
  app/controllers/weekly_query_controller.rb:15:in `next_release'
```

#### releae_schedule.rb

```
class ReleaseSchedule
  scope :next_release, ->(){ ReleaseSchedule.where(:release_date.gte => Time.now).without(:_id, :created_at, :updated_at).first }
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not really a scope at all, that's just a class method wrapped up to look like a scope. There are two problems:

1. You're saying `ReleaseSchedule.where(...)` so you can't chain the "scope" (i.e. `ReleaseSchedule.where(...).next_release` won't do what it is supposed to do).
2. Your "scope" ends in `first` so it won't return a query, it just returns a single instance.

**2** is probably where your NoMethodError comes from.

If you really want it to be a scope for some reason then you'd say:

```
# No `first` or explicit class reference in here.
scope :next_release, -> { where(:release_date.gte => Time.now).without(:_id, :created_at, :updated_at) }
```

and use it as:

```
# The `first` goes here instead.
r = ReleaseSchedule.next_release.first
```

But really, you just want a class method:

```
def self.next_release
  where(:release_date.gte => Time.now).without(:_id, :created_at, :updated_at).first
end
```

The `scope` macro is, after all, just a fancy way to build class methods. The only reason we have `scope` is to express an intent (i.e. to build queries piece by piece) and what you're doing doesn't match that intent.